# Given the number of tokens, how to find corresponding closest number of lines within a file?

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed, grep

Given a huge file which contains text (one sentence per line), the task is to extract N tokens (for example 100 million tokens out of 3 billion), since I can not break a sentence into parts, I need to find closest number of lines that contains given number of tokens.

I tried following code:

```
perl -p -e 's/\n/ #/g' huge_file | cut -d' ' -f1-100000000 | grep -o ' #' | wc -w
```

which replace newline symbol with symbol ' #' (we are basically joining sentences into single line) and counting number of symbol ' #' which should correspond to number of sentence (huge_file doesn't contain '#' symbol). However, grep can not process the large line and giving 'grep: memory exhausted' error. Is there any other efficient way for accomplishing task, that would also work for very large files?

Comment: Can you give some sample line ?

Comment: What prevents you from using `awk` and accumulating `NF`, if you just need to extract the first 100 million tokens?

Comment: sorry, but my file is very huge, I can not post whole file (I am actually using gigaword corpus). format of my file is as following:
sentence1
sentence2
...
sentence K
Every sentence contains around 10-30 tokens (words)

Comment: 4ae1e1, because I can not break line, I need number of lines that contains around 100 million (as close as possible to 100 million)

Comment: `awk '{ num_tokens += NF; if (num_tokens >= 100000000) { print NR; exit; } }' huge_file` Hopefully I understood your problem.

Comment: @4ae1e1, I confirm that your solution works, I didn't compare it to other methods (in terms of time), but it solves my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Does time even matter for a number as small as 100000000? Think of CPU frequencies these days. Programmer time is much more valuable. I can't imagine anything better than awk at handling this (better in terms of simplicity), due to the line processing nature and builtin NF and NR.

Comment: With some sample data and a clearer task description, there's almost certainly a better solution that doesn't involve about 5 piped commands like that. Both `awk` and `perl` can do line processing and word counting and bail out after a particular number of either.

Answer (score 1):

I had a bit of a hard time understanding what you're asking. But I think you're tackling it very badly. Running `perl` as a super-sed, then `cut`, then `grep` then `wc` is horribly inefficient.

If I understand correctly, you want as many lines as it takes to get at least 100M words.

Why not instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $wordcount = 0; 

#use 'magic' filehandle - read piped input or 
#command line specified 'myscript.pl somefilename' - just like sed/grep
while ( <> )  
    #split on whitespace, count number of fields. Or words in this case. 
    $wordcount += scalar split; 
    #chomp; if you don't want the line feed here
    #print current line 
    print; 
    #bail out if our wordcount is above a certain number. 
    last if $wordcount >= 100_000_000
    #NB $. is line number if you wanted to just do a certain number of lines. 
} 

#already printed the content with line feeds intact. 
#this prints the precise count we've printed. 
print $wordcount," words printed\n";
```

This will iterate your file, and as soon as you've seen 100M words, it'll bail out - meaning you no longer have to read the whole file, nor do you need to invoke a daisy chain of commands.

This would oneliner if you're really insistent:

```
perl -p -e '$wordcount += scalar split; last if $wordcount > 100_000_000;'
```

Again - I couldn't quite tell what the significance of line feeds and `#` symbols were, so I haven't done anything with them. But `s/\n/ #/` works fine in the above code block, as does `chomp;` to remove trailing linefeeds if that's what you're after.